# Empty file input from .clone()

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm trying to clone a file input form, which every time I select a file *then* click "add more" to clone the file input, but it has copied the selected file in the input.

```
<input type="file" />
<span id="add-more-files">Add more</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#add-more-files').click(function()
{
   var cloned = $(this).prev().clone();
   $(cloned).insertBefore($(this));
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tH4HG/).

Now whenever you select a file before cloning the previous, you can see it has the same file selected, I need it to be empty when cloned.

**EDIT:**

How would I be able to clone this, referring to [Neal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598613/empty-file-input-from-clone/5598685#5598685)?

```
<div class="wrap"><input type="file /></div>
<span id="add-more-files">Add more</span>
```

Comment: what browser are u using? in chrome it gets emptied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can try is:

```
$('#add-more-files').click(function()
{
   var cloned = $(this).prev().clone();
   cloned.val(null);
   $(cloned).insertBefore($(this));
});
```

**UPDATE**
or if all the inputs will be copies from the previous just create a new one instead of cloning:

```
$('#add-more-files').click(function()
{
   var cloned = $(this).prev();
   $('<input>',{type:cloned.attr('type')}).insertBefore($(this));
});
```

Comment: This won't work, you can't edit the value of an `<input>` of type file for security reasons.

Comment: His original code doesn't use `.val()` on an `<input>` of type `file`.

Comment: @Drackir my new part has nothing to do with `val()`

Comment: You should remove the first part since it doesn't work. The second one should work for what the Asker wants. Also, you don't need to clone the object or wrap `this` in `insertBefore()`. Good idea. :)

Comment: Pretty good piece of code. Have you tried having a parent wrap (`div`) and cloning it?

Comment: @lolwut u already accepted an answer, create a enw question and ill be glad to answer that one :-D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598954/cloning-an-element-with-file-input-child-and-emptying-it

Comment: The first part, as @RichardMarskell-Drackir said, won't work. The second part isn't cloning.

Answer (score 1):

The only workable solution I found is to provide the file input field as a template that is hidden. Then a clone is created after the page is loaded to provide the first field.

It also works without an "add more" button, instead it adds a new file input field when the last one is filled in.

```html
<div id="files">
    <input type="file" name="files" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

```js
function AddUploadElement()
{
    var newUploadElement = $("#files").children(":first-child").clone();
    newUploadElement.css("display", "");

    $("#files").append(newUploadElement);
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    AddUploadElement();

    $("#files").on("change", "input", function ()
    {
        if ($(this).is(":last-child") == true)
        {
            AddUploadElement();
        }
    });
});
```

The cloning part is important because the template input field might have additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The [jquery.fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L882) plugin circumvents the issue of clearing file inputs like this:

```
var inputClone = input.clone(true);
$('<form></form>').append(inputClone)[0].reset();
input.after(inputClone).detach();
```

i.e. clone the input, append to a temporary form to reset it, and detach the input so that it can be appended to forms consecutively.

then you can `input.replaceWith(inputClone);`