# Cloning an element with file input child and emptying it

Tags: jquery, clone

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598613/empty-file-input-from-clone) I need a solution for it:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" />
<span id="add-more-files">Add more</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#add-more-files').click(function()
{
   var cloned = $(this).prev().clone();
   $(cloned).insertBefore($(this));
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is substantively different than your first question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* You really should ask a new question, don't just copy your old one and make people jump around to figure out what you want.

Assuming the HTML:

```
<div class="wrap"><input type="file" /></div>
<span id="add-more-files">Add more</span>
```

You can do:

```
$('#add-more-files').click(function(){
    $("<div>", {class:"wrap"}) //Create a div
        .append($("<input>", {type:'file'})) //Add an input element
        .insertBefore(this); //Insert it into the DOM
});
```

This creates a new div and input tag structure and then inserts it into the DOM before the clickable span. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tH4HG/5/) for a working example.

Note: It doesn't insert a new input into the same div. If that's what you wanted see @jAX's answer.

Comment: You're not cloning the element.

Comment: @Stijn I solved the asker's problem and answered their question. Note that at the end of the title it says "and emptying it". It's not possible to do this while cloning the element so you have to create a new one. I don't think the down vote is warranted, but if you want to give out votes without reading the question fully or understanding the problem, I guess that's your prerogative.

Comment: Please see my answer to the original question linked in this one for a solution that does cloning, and for why this method is not adequate. I'm not saying my method is ideal, but it does what I came looking here for in the first place. I'm willing to undo my downvote, because you're right in the sense that the answer works for the particular case in the question, but you'll have to modify your answer before SO will let me do so.

Comment: @Stijn I like your solution in the other question. You could still make copies with classes/other attributes by changing my code a little but yours does benefit from the separation of HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#add-more-files').click(function()
{
   $('<input type="file" />').insertBefore($(this));
});
```